# Is there a way with list comprehension with fixed length?

Tags: python

If I do list_comprehension I want to exclude an special element but I want to have a fixed length.

Let j the special element. The comprehension

```
[i for i in liste if i != j]
```

doesnt have a fixed length. How I can gurantee a fixed list length of this list comprehension?

Comment: What do you mean by fixed length? What would the fixed length be?

Comment: Please add an example with your input, current output and expected output.

Comment: Provide a concrete example of what you want.  Your description does not adequately describe your goal.

Answer (score 2):

You can slice the result of the list comprehension to the desired size. Providing its length is sufficient, you will obtain lists of constant size.

```
[i for i in liste if i != j][:final_size]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question it's a bit unclear, but I think I can help you.

You can use enumerate inside you loop to keep the index and limit elements with another if condition.

```
>>> limit = 2
>>> liste = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> [j for i, j in enumerate(liste) if i < limit]
['a', 'b']
```

I've used `limit` as the maximum length of the list.